# Disadvantages of Qt for desktop applications over platform vendor preferred toolkit

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Qt is the native toolkit for development of  applications targeted for KDE, but also may be used to create desktop applications targeted for GNOME, Windows, and macOS.

The same build of an application is used for either KDE versus GNOME environments, with the latter generally supplying Qt themes to produce similar visual effects compared to GTK themes. Windows and macOS builds are separate targets, and in either case the native widget framework of the platform is employed.

How do results compare for Qt applications versus those written with the preferred toolkits for each platform?

In particular...

- Compared to writing applications in GTK, what is the disadvantage of writing in Qt for targeting GNOME environments?
- Compared to using Microsoft preferred tools, what is the disadvantage of writing in Qt for targeting a Windows application?
- Compared to using Apple preferred tools, what is the disadvantage of writing in Qt for targeting a macOS application?

Please note that the scope of the question exceeds simply graphical user interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for GTK (since I've never used it), but in general the most obvious disadvantage of writing to Qt APIs instead of directly to native Windows or MacOS/X APIs is that your app will be using Qt's emulation of the native OS's "look and feel", rather than using the native functionality directly.  In general this works okay, but it does result in some rough edges:

1. Sometimes the painting logic used by Qt's [QStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyle.html) renderers doesn't quite match the OS's native imagery, resulting in minor discrepancies between a Qt app and native-written apps, that users may or may not notice.
2. If/when the GUI appearance rendered by the OS's native APIs changes in some backwards-compatible way, all native-API-targetting apps will automatically use the new/updated appearance, but Qt-based apps will not (since Qt-based apps don't use the native APIs to render their widgets).  You'll have to wait for a newer version of Qt to come out that (hopefully) emulates the "new native appearance", and in the meantime your app will look a bit clunky and dated next to comparable native apps.  (This has happened several times on the MacOS/X side, e.g. when Apple changed the "standard look" of its apps from blue-pinstripes to gray slate, and later to, erm, whatever they call MacOS's current look)
3. There exists on each OS various native APIs whose functionality isn't exposed by any corresponding cross-platform Qt API.  You can still access these APIs in your Qt app by calling out to the native API directly, of course, but if you're targeting multiple platforms, that means you'll need to write separate native-API-calling code for each platform you want to support, which is what Qt is (supposed to) help you avoid.
4. Writing to Qt APIs means your app will (typically) need to bundle the Qt libraries into its installer in order to run, since Qt libraries are not-pre-installed in most OS's and asking the user to install them separately is considered user-unfriendly.  This adds a few dozen megabytes to your app's download and to its installed footprint.
5. Qt's APIs may (or may not) suit your purpose better than the OS's native APIs ... that's probably a matter of taste.  I think Qt is very good for a C++ API, but you might find something like Swift or C# to be a better fit for your purposes than anything C++ can provide.

Of course, the upside of using Qt is that you only have to write and maintain a single codebase, rather than a separate codebase for each platform you want your application to ship on.  For a small development team, that advantage can make up for a lot.

Comment: I have understood that applications developed under recent versions of Qt utilize native widgets for Windows and macOS, rather than emulating them. Is this information inaccurate?

Comment: I'm not sure how much of the native API is incorporated into Qt (vs. emulating it). Though, I noticed that the `QDrag` uses the Windows drag&drop including its draw backs that e.g. key events are mostly suppressed while D&D is in progress. Another example are Qt palette colors in selection of `QTreeView` / `QTableView`. While the visual appearance matches the Windows (default) palette, they don't match the `QPalette` values which can be retrieved. A look into the source code may uncover more details...

Comment: @brainchild Qt never instantiated native widgets -- the reason being that in general a widget on platform A and a widget on platform B behave differently enough that it's often difficult or impossible to write a wrapper API that works consistently for both of them.  As of Qt 4.x, Qt doesn't even create a native handle for the widgets it renders... the native OS APIs only know about the existence of the top-level Qt window, it doesn't know about the contents of that window.  That was done for performance reasons.  (see:  https://www.qt.io/blog/2011/02/23/alien-widgets-on-mac )

Comment: It is hard to understand, but Wikipedia reports: "When first released, Qt used its own paint engine and controls, emulating the look of the different platforms it runs on when it drew its widgets. This made the porting work easier because very few classes in Qt really depended on the target platform; however, this occasionally led to slight discrepancies where that emulation was imperfect. Recent versions of Qt use the native style APIs of the different platforms, on platforms that have a native widget set, to query metrics and draw most controls, and do not suffer from such issues as often."

Comment: Note that the reference is now dated by over 11 years.

Comment: @brainchild I can assure you that Qt has not switched back to native widgets since then.  (if it had, I would have noticed, because the performance of my Qt app which instantiates a large number of QWidgets, would have dropped back to the lesser level it exhibited back when it was being built against 3.x and older 4.x Qt versions :) )

Comment: @brainchild the Wikipedia article is referring to Qt using native APIs to gather hints about how it should draw widgets -- but Qt still does the actual drawing of the widgets itself, rather than relying on the native OS to draw widgets on Qt's behalf.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think it is easy to be misled by the Wikipedia article, but I understand how your explanation follows the text. It is somewhat disappointing to learn that Qt applications are not rendered through the same means as those fully native.

Comment: @brainchild I think the notion of native is a misbegotten one for Windows (though valid for Linux and Apple systems). What is native on Windows? Win32? MFC? WinUI? WinForms? WPF? UWPs? Microsoft itself seems to have given up on the notion of a native GUI toolkit. Nonetheless, Qt applications leverage what they can from Microsoft for basic controls and otherwise their own implementation (similar to WPF insofar as they use a single HWND) which is often equal or superior to Microsoft's. Certainly nothing to complain about.